# Como fazer o navegador renderizar o <span> com alguns espaços no texto?

Tags: html, css, espaço-em-branco

Tenho uma `<div>` que servirá para armazenar informações. Eu quero fazer uma espécie de "tabela", formatando os textos e os valores para que fiquem mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
Hot Dog    2,99
Pizza         7
Carro     91000
Lasanha Sd.  13
```

É um exemplo bem tosco mesmo mas é nesse formato que eu quero meu texto. Para realizar esta tarefa, eu tentei utilizar o código abaixo:

```
const info = document.getElementById("info");
info.innerHTML = "";

const totalEpisodes = `<span>${getTotalEpisodesWatched(list).padStart(10)}</span><br/>`;
const meanScore = `<span>${getMeanScore(list).padStart(10)}</span><br/>`;

info.innerHTML += "Total Episodes:".padEnd(15) + totalEpisodes;
info.innerHTML += "Mean Score:".padEnd(15) + meanScore;
```

O problema é que quando eu criei esse código, eu esqueci completamente que os espaços não iriam aparecer no resultado final. Eu sei que posso utilizar o `&nbsp;` para gerar um TAB mas o que preciso é realmente de espaçamentos em branco para realizar a formatação corretamente.

Então a minha dúvida é: como posso fazer o navegador renderizar os espaços no elemento?

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar uma `table` ou `grid` para isso? Linhas podem quebrar e perder a formatação, e se o seu site for renderizado com uma fonte não mono-espaçada vai ficar estranho.

Comment: Só pra constar que `&nbsp;` não é um tab. Alem disso, porque você não adiciona um _code snippet_?

Comment: @user140828 sim eu pensei em usar um `<table>`, porém não quero aquelas linhas da tabela e não quero aquela formatação padrão dela. Se for para usar um `<table>` eu quero que a tabela fiquei com a cara de uma `<div>` (sem linha, borda, ou qualquer outro detalhe) e com a formatação que eu mostrei na pergunta.

Comment: @LuizFelipe se eu fosse usar um *code snippet* para representar o que eu tento fazer no código, ficaria muito grande a pergunta pois eu precisaria colocar o HTML, etc, etc. Então eu coloquei apenas a parte do código JS que é o mais importante.

Comment: E como eu falei no comentário acima, não me importo de utilizar `<table>` contanto que eu consiga a formatação que eu quero. Mas ainda assim como a pergunta é sobre renderizar espaços em branco no browser, seria bom uma resposta sobre isso para ajudar outras pessoas e não só a mim.

Comment: Espaço em branco é `&nbsp;`. Dois espaços em branco `&ensp;`. Quatro espaços em branco `&emsp;`

Comment: Chegou a ver isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/421374/112052?

Comment: Chegou a ver isso (2): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454404/alinhamento-de-elementos-no-html-e-css/454432#454432

Comment: Esqueça a formatação no seu código! O correto é usar CSS. Código é para processar; CSS é para formatar. Mas, como sei que todo programador é cabeça-dura, se você quiser **muito** usar seu código da forma como o escreveu, você sempre pode usar as tags &lt;pre&gt; ... &lt;/pre&gt;.

Comment: @hkotsubo era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando. Eu não achei no site antes essa questão porque o título da pergunta não deixava claro que era sobre espaços em branco em HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ser sincero com você, não faz sentido você querer reinventar a roda. Se você quer simplesmente mostrar informações de uma forma tabulada, o elemento `<table>` é ideal para o que você precisa, bastando formatar algumas células com a propriedade `text-align`, veja:

```css
#info tr td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="info">
  <tr>
    <td>Hot Dog</td>
    <td>2,99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pizza</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Carro</td>
    <td>91000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lasanha Sd.</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note que por padrão a tabela não mostra bordas.

Além de você estar utilizando o elemento próprio para isso, você não precisa de gerenciar a lógica de espaços no JavaScript, deixando isso a cargo do CSS.

Existem alguns poucos casos em que tabelas não são ideal para mostrar dados tabelados (como recriar uma planilha do estilo do Excel), mas não creio que esse simples quadro de informações seja um deles. :)

Comment: Luiz o código CSS não está funcionando aqui. Eu copiei e colei certinho o código CSS da resposta porém ele não afeta o `<td>`.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Você modificou o HTML? Simplesmente não funciona...? 

Comment: Simplesmente não funciona. E uma coisa que ta me deixando aflito, é que os `tr` estão dentro do `<tbody>` que está dentro da `<table>`. Estou inserindo os dados na tabela dessa forma table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>Dado:</td><td>${dado}</td></tr>`;

Comment: Você chegou a ver se o CSS funciona no _snippet_ acima? Porque aqui está funcionando.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar. Tava dando problema por algum motivo porque eu criei as `<tr>` com `innerHTML` ao invés de usar o `.createElement`. Obrigado Luiz.

Comment: Luiz o código funciona mas o `tr` não possui a mesma largura da tabela. Sendo assim os dados não ficam "encostando" ao lado direito da tabela como deveria. O que devo fazer?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, nesse caso acho melhor você abrir uma outra pergunta para tentar exemplificar um pouco melhor o seu problema. Uma outra opção é irmos para o chat. :-)

Comment: To achando que se eu abrir uma outra pergunta eu vou tomar uma chuva de downvote que nem nessa ;p Melhor ir para o chat mesmo.